# Setting Speakker on Autoplay & Shuffle?

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I have stumbled upon a great HTML5 Audio player [Speakker](http://www.speakker.com/) but I don't know If I can set it up on autoplay + shuffle on. Have anyone tried this? Or any workaround it via jquery? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for ayto play...

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">  
    <source src="file.ogg" />  
    <source src="file.mp3" />       
</audio>
```

for shuffle give the audio sourse dynamically using jquery by using random number concept.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not really asking for the bare html5. Its a jquery plugin that creates a nice playlist. I just can't see on its documentation where/how to set it the autoplay and shuffle on.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question, may be following is your answer.

In Html

```
<audio  id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="../../Content/telephonRing.mp3" ></audio>
```

In Jquery

```
     $("#audio-player")[0].play();//To play
      $("#audio-player")[0].pause(); //To pause

//For Ringtone will repeat
      $("#audio-player")[0].addEventListener('ended', function () {
                    this.currentTime = 0;
                    this.play();
                }, false);
```

Comment: No. I'm actually asking someone who have already tried the plugin extensively (Speakker / http://speakker.com)